# gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: Could not execute operation due to backend exception

Tags: janusgraph, gremlinpython

This problem does not seem to be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57606708/6946463).

I am trying to execute a long-running database population job, but after a few hours it fails at seemingly random times. I am running JanusGraph 1.0.0 through the Docker image, and I'm using gremlinpython 3.5.8.

The code below attempts creating 10M vertices and about 90M edges. It uses to fold/coalesce/unfold pattern to only create them if they don't already exist. There is also no batching of operations, so this is extremely slow but is expected to work.

```py
import os
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __, GraphTraversalSource
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection


load_dotenv()

GRAPH_DB_HOST = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_HOST")
GRAPH_DB_USER = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_USER")
GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD")
GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT = os.getenv("GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT")
GRAPH_DB_URL = f"ws://{GRAPH_DB_HOST}:{GREMLIN_SEVER_PORT}/gremlin"


g: GraphTraversalSource = traversal().withRemote(
    DriverRemoteConnection(GRAPH_DB_URL, 'g',
                           username=GRAPH_DB_USER,
                           password=GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD)
)

vertices_to_add = 10_000_000

my_traversal = g
progress_bar = tqdm(total=vertices_to_add)
progress_bar.set_description("Adding vertices")

# add vertices in chunks of size chunk_size
for i in range(vertices_to_add):
    g.V().has('person', 'output_id', i) \
        .fold() \
        .coalesce(
        __.unfold(),
        __.addV('person').property('output_id', i)
    ).next()

    # create vertices from the last 10 people
    if i > 10:
        for j in range(1, 11):
            g.V().has('person', 'output_id', i - j) \
                 .inE('my_edge').where(__.outV().has('person', 'output_id', i)) \
                 .fold() \
                 .coalesce(__.unfold(),
                           __.V().has('person', 'output_id', i)
                           .addE('my_edge')
                           .from_(__.V().has('person', 'output_id', i - j))
                           .property('value', random.randint(1, 1000))
                           ).next()

    progress_bar.update(1)

progress_bar.close()
```

```
ERROR:root:
Received error message '{'requestId': '0127041d-376c-4754-802d-a68549418d23', 'status': {'message': 'Could not execute operation due to backend exception', 'code': 500, 'attributes': {'stackTrace': 'org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:54)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.executeRead(BackendTransaction.java:521)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.edgeStoreQuery(BackendTransaction.java:284)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.multiThreadedEdgeStoreMultiQuery(BackendTransaction.java:355)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.edgeStoreMultiQuery(BackendTransaction.java:313)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.edgeMultiQuery(StandardJanusGraph.java:568)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.lambda$executeMultiQuery$4(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1252)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.profile.QueryProfiler.profile(QueryProfiler.java:113)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.profile.QueryProfiler.profile(QueryProfiler.java:105)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.executeMultiQuery(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1252)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.execute(MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:121)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.properties(MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:179)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.preFetch(MultiVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:185)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.fetcher.HasStepBatchFetcher.prefetchNextPropertiesBatch(HasStepBatchFetcher.java:147)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.fetcher.HasStepBatchFetcher.prefetchNextBatch(HasStepBatchFetcher.java:112)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.fetcher.MultiQueriableStepBatchFetcher.fetchData(MultiQueriableStepBatchFetcher.java:96)\n\tat org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphHasStep.filter(JanusGraphHasStep.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.FilterStep.processNextStart(FilterStep.java:41)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.hasNext(DefaultTraversal.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.TraversalUtil.test(TraversalUtil.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.TraversalFilterStep.filter(TraversalFilterStep.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.FilterStep.processNextStart(FilterStep.java:41)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.hasNext(ExpandableStepIterator.java:47)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ReducingBarrierStep.processAllStarts(ReducingBarrierStep.java:110)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ReducingBarrierStep.processNextStart(ReducingBarrierStep.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.FlatMapStep.processNextStart(FlatMapStep.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.hasNext(DefaultTraversal.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.TraverserIterator.fillBulker(TraverserIterator.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.TraverserIterator.hasNext(TraverserIterator.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor.handleIterator(TraversalOpProcessor.java:350)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor.lambda$iterateBytecodeTraversal$0(TraversalOpProcessor.java:223)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Permanent exception while executing backend operation EdgeStoreQuery\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:79)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52)\n\t... 41 more\nCaused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: (JE 18.3.12) Environment must be closed, caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: Environment invalid because of previous exception: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data Latch timeout. BIN4 currentThread: Thread[JEEvictor,5,main] currentTime: 1704951452786 exclusiveOwner: Thread[Backend[30],5,main] UNEXPECTED_STATE_FATAL: Unexpected internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException.wrapSelf(EnvironmentFailureException.java:230)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkIfInvalid(EnvironmentImpl.java:1835)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkOpen(EnvironmentImpl.java:1844)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.Environment.checkOpen(Environment.java:2697)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.Database.checkEnv(Database.java:2413)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.Database.openCursor(Database.java:939)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJETx.openCursor(BerkeleyJETx.java:63)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.openCursor(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:95)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.getSlice(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:155)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.getSlice(OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.java:88)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.getSlice(KCVSProxy.java:82)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:287)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:284)\n\tat org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66)\n\t... 42 more\nCaused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: Environment invalid because of previous exception: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data Latch timeout. BIN4 currentThread: Thread[JEEvictor,5,main] currentTime: 1704951452786 exclusiveOwner: Thread[Backend[30],5,main] UNEXPECTED_STATE_FATAL: Unexpected internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException.unexpectedState(EnvironmentFailureException.java:459)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchSupport.handleTimeout(LatchSupport.java:211)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchImpl.acquireExclusive(LatchImpl.java:63)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchImpl.acquireShared(LatchImpl.java:107)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.tree.IN.latchShared(IN.java:563)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.latchChildShared(Tree.java:353)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.search(Tree.java:2255)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.search(Tree.java:2152)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.searchExact(CursorImpl.java:1972)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.searchExact(CursorImpl.java:1935)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbTree.getDb(DbTree.java:1708)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbTree.getDb(DbTree.java:1659)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor$DbCache.getDb(Evictor.java:3394)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor.evictBatch(Evictor.java:2394)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor.doEvict(Evictor.java:2262)\n\tat com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor$BackgroundEvictTask.run(Evictor.java:3297)\n\t... 3 more\n', 'exceptions': ['org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException', 'org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException', 'com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException', 'com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException']}}, 'result': {'data': None, 'meta': {}}}'

With results dictionary '{'0127041d-376c-4754-802d-a68549418d23': <gremlin_python.driver.resultset.ResultSet object at 0x7f28233dd790>}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/graph_populate.py", line 432, in <module>
    else:
         
  File "/app/src/graph_populate.py", line 184, in populate_outputs_onebyone_getorcreate
    raise e
  File "/app/src/graph_populate.py", line 177, in populate_outputs_onebyone_getorcreate
    ).next()
      ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 88, in next
    return self.__next__()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 47, in __next__
    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 548, in apply_strategies
    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connection.py", line 80, in apply
    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 103, in submit
    results = result_set.all().result()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 90, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 90, in _receive
    status_code = self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 133, in data_received
    raise GremlinServerError(message['status'])
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
```

It should be mentioned that I have added additional configuration options in my `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`, mainly regarding memory, as an attempt at reducing issues with large, long-running operations, and to increase speed.

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
  btc_janus:
    build:
      context: ./janusgraph/
    container_name: btc_janus
    shm_size: 2g
    ports:
      - "${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}:${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}"
      - "8484:8184"
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - btc-network
    volumes:
      - ${GRAPH_DB_FOLDER:-./data/btc_janus}:/var/lib/janusgraph
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 4
    environment:
      janusgraph.storage.backend: berkeleyje
      janusgraph.tx.log-tx: true
      janusgraph.tx.max-commit-time: 100000000000
```

And the following Dockerfile:

```
#  ./janusgraph/Dockerfile

FROM janusgraph/janusgraph:latest

# "-Xmx8g -Xms8g" crashes the container, and "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" is not supported
ENV JAVA_OPTS=" -Xss4096k "
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xss4096k"
ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xss4096k"

# Copy the index creation script
COPY create_index.groovy /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_index.groovy
```

For brevity, I have not included the JanusGraph server logs, but here is a snippet of them:

```
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:79) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 ... 41 more
2024-01-10 21:37:32 Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: (JE 18.3.12) Environment must be closed, caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: Environment invalid because of previous exception: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data Latch timeout. BIN4 currentThread: Thread[JEEvictor,5,main] currentTime: 1704951452786 exclusiveOwner: Thread[Backend[30],5,main] UNEXPECTED_STATE_FATAL: Unexpected internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException.wrapSelf(EnvironmentFailureException.java:230) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkIfInvalid(EnvironmentImpl.java:1835) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkOpen(EnvironmentImpl.java:1844) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.checkOpen(Environment.java:2697) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.Database.checkEnv(Database.java:2413) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.Database.openCursor(Database.java:939) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJETx.openCursor(BerkeleyJETx.java:63) ~[janusgraph-berkeleyje-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.openCursor(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:95) ~[janusgraph-berkeleyje-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.getSlice(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:155) ~[janusgraph-berkeleyje-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.getSlice(OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.java:88) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.getSlice(KCVSProxy.java:82) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:287) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:284) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 ... 41 more
2024-01-10 21:37:32 Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: Environment invalid because of previous exception: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data Latch timeout. BIN4 currentThread: Thread[JEEvictor,5,main] currentTime: 1704951452786 exclusiveOwner: Thread[Backend[30],5,main] UNEXPECTED_STATE_FATAL: Unexpected internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException.unexpectedState(EnvironmentFailureException.java:459) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchSupport.handleTimeout(LatchSupport.java:211) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchImpl.acquireExclusive(LatchImpl.java:63) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.latch.LatchImpl.acquireShared(LatchImpl.java:107) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.tree.IN.latchShared(IN.java:563) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.latchChildShared(Tree.java:353) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.search(Tree.java:2255) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.tree.Tree.search(Tree.java:2152) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.searchExact(CursorImpl.java:1972) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.searchExact(CursorImpl.java:1935) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbTree.getDb(DbTree.java:1708) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbTree.getDb(DbTree.java:1659) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor$DbCache.getDb(Evictor.java:3394) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor.evictBatch(Evictor.java:2394) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor.doEvict(Evictor.java:2262) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.sleepycat.je.evictor.Evictor$BackgroundEvictTask.run(Evictor.java:3297) ~[je-18.3.12.jar:18.3.12]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 ... 3 more
2024-01-10 21:37:32 05:37:32 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor.lambda$iterateBytecodeTraversal$0 - Exception processing a Traversal on iteration for request [7ec2741e-ef77-4f96-9954-06295d0cb41d].
2024-01-10 21:37:32 org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:54) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.executeRead(BackendTransaction.java:521) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.edgeStoreQuery(BackendTransaction.java:284) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.edgeQuery(StandardJanusGraph.java:558) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.lambda$null$0(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:124) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.profile.QueryProfiler.profile(QueryProfiler.java:113) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.profile.QueryProfiler.profile(QueryProfiler.java:105) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.profile.QueryProfiler.profile(QueryProfiler.java:101) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.lambda$getBasicIterator$1(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:124) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex.loadRelations(CacheVertex.java:73) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.getBasicIterator(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:124) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.iterator(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:80) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$5.iterator(Iterables.java:742) ~[guava-32.1.3-jre.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.vertexIds(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:103) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.executeIndividualVertices(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:365) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.executeVertices(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:359) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder$VertexConstructor.getResult(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:266) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder$VertexConstructor.getResult(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:262) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.VertexCentricQueryBuilder.execute(VertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:106) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.VertexCentricQueryBuilder.vertices(VertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:134) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.getVertexLabelInternal(AbstractVertex.java:126) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.vertexLabel(AbstractVertex.java:131) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.label(AbstractVertex.java:122) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.system.ImplicitKey.computeProperty(ImplicitKey.java:94) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.executeImplicitKeyQuery(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:236) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.VertexCentricQueryBuilder.properties(VertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:119) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.ElementHelper.getValues(ElementHelper.java:48) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.condition.PredicateCondition.evaluate(PredicateCondition.java:72) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.condition.And.evaluate(And.java:55) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQuery.matches(GraphCentricQuery.java:157) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.lambda$getFilterIterator$2(QueryProcessor.java:138) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.CloseableIteratorUtils$1.computeNext(CloseableIteratorUtils.java:51) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145) ~[guava-32.1.3-jre.jar:?]
2024-01-10 21:37:32 at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140) ~[guava-32.1.3-jre.jar:?]
```

I can't help but continually notice `com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: Environment invalid because of previous exception: (JE 18.3.12) /var/lib/janusgraph/data Latch timeout. BIN4 currentThread: Thread[JEEvictor,5,main] currentTime: 1704951452786 exclusiveOwner: Thread[Backend[30],5,main] UNEXPECTED_STATE_FATAL: Unexpected internal state, unable to continue. Environment is invalid and must be closed.`. This seems to be the culprit of the issue.